# VBA, add compare values listbox combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, listbox, compare

in a userform i have a listbox and a combobox, listbox will receive values from combobox via a button 'Add',i need to write a control to check if the values selected in combobox already exist in listbox , if it exist a beep will be played if not the value will be added. this is one of some tested codes, the control of empty values is working well but cannot add vlues or tst controls.

```
If etatgen.Value = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox ("Non authorized value")
    Exit Sub
Else
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To (lstetatgen.ListCount - 1)
        If lstetatgen.List(i) = etatgen.Value Then
            Exit for
        Else
            lstetatgen.AddItem etatgen.Value
        End If
    Next
End If
```

thanks

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: sorry, original post updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem by editing my code this is a sample

```
 existant = 0
 non_existant = 0


If etatgen.Value = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox ("Valeur vide non autorisée")
    Exit Sub
Else
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To (lstetatgen.ListCount - 1)
           If lstetatgen.List(i) = etatgen.Value Then
            MsgBox ("Existant")
            existant = 1
        Else
            non_existant = 1
        End If

    Next i


End If
If existant = 1 Then
Else
lstetatgen.AddItem etatgen.Value
End If
Exit Sub
```